# Script that makes all floating divs the same height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hey there, I have 20 divs floated left with different height. I use this script to resize them. It worked perfect when my website was designed using pixels.

When i have changed my website to % design (percentage design), the script stopped working that reliable, sometimes it does not resize.

can you take a look, see if there are any adjustments needed for liquid layouts?

maybe it's the way i call the script?

Ty very much

Here it is:

```
var currentTallest = 0;
var currentRowStart = 0;
var rowDivs = new Array();

function setConformingHeight(el, newHeight) {
 // set the height to something new, but remember the original height in case things change
 el.data("originalHeight", (el.data("originalHeight") == undefined) ? (el.height()) : (el.data("originalHeight")));
 el.height(newHeight);
}

function getOriginalHeight(el) {
 // if the height has changed, send the originalHeight
 return (el.data("originalHeight") == undefined) ? (el.height()) : (el.data("originalHeight"));
}

function columnConform() {

 // find the tallest DIV in the row, and set the heights of all of the DIVs to match it.
 $('div.column').each(function(index) {

  if(currentRowStart != $(this).position().top) {

   // we just came to a new row.  Set all the heights on the completed row
   for(currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) setConformingHeight(rowDivs[currentDiv], currentTallest);

   // set the variables for the new row
   rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
   currentRowStart = $(this).position().top;
   currentTallest = getOriginalHeight($(this));
   rowDivs.push($(this));

  } else {

   // another div on the current row.  Add it to the list and check if it's taller
   rowDivs.push($(this));
   currentTallest = (currentTallest < getOriginalHeight($(this))) ? (getOriginalHeight($(this))) : (currentTallest);

  }
  // do the last row
  for(currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) setConformingHeight(rowDivs[currentDiv], currentTallest);

 });

}

$(window).resize(function() {
 columnConform();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
 columnConform();
});
```

Comment: for your page layout, you should consider css... mostly

Comment: What's `% desing` (in the text of the question)?

Comment: Liquid desing, where all the divs are in percent

Comment: Oh I got it now.  A percent-based design.

Comment: posting html layout will help to analyze the issue...

Comment: Seems really complicated for the intended use... Why not just get the biggest height, and set every div to that height ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you change it to fluid layout (% design) then you are going to have to add a window resize listener, basically when the resize event is done or while it's running you need to recall the script so it can recalculate with new dimensions, you did not need to doo that with pixels because it was a fixed size and once assigned will not change no matter how many times you resize the actual screen.

Comment: Isn't it added inside the code above? how can i do it, please give me an example?

Comment: you are actually right the resize is taken care of in your code within this block:
$(window).resize(function() {
 columnConform();
});

Please post some of the html so I can help you debug it.

Comment: you can put the code on jsfiddle.net as well if you want and post the url, whatever works for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use styles like this:

```
<style>
    .parent{
        background:#F00;height:300px
    }
    .parent div{
        float:left;height:100%;width:33.33%;
    }
</style>
<div class="parent">
    <div style="background:#FED"></div>
    <div style="background:#EDF"></div>
    <div style="background:#DFE"></div>
</div>
```

You just have to set the height of the parent `div`, and the width of the children `div`